Do you say "You got the floor muddy" the same way we say "get something wet / dirty"?
I am not a native English speaker so I rely mostly on dictionaries.
Normally, dictionaries have examples using structures of "get something/ somebody wet" or "get something/ somebody dirty". They seldom have examples using "make something/ somebody wet" or "make something/ somebody dirty"
For example,
Try not to get your shoes wet.
She didn't want to get her dress dirty.
I remember when I say "I made my clothes dirty/wet", some people say they don't sound like native English.
However, dictionaries seldom use the structure of "get something muddy", but, most of the time, "make something muddy".
For example,
The rain had made the field very muddy.
The rain had made the football pitch extremely muddy.
Although, they do say "somebody/ something gets muddy"
For example,
We all got a bit muddy and wet.
Do you say "You got the floor muddy" the same way we say "get something wet / dirty"?

Note that your  post’s body and title ask different things. I suggest you edit at least one of them to bring them into alignment.

to make something x is not to get something x.

To make something muddy is to cause mud to form, as rain on bare earth does.
To get something muddy is to cause (already existing) mud to stick to the thing or penetrate into it, as by treading in mud and then onto the thing.

a chatbot says "get sth muddy" is more passive and normally by accident while "make sth muddy" is more active and normally on purpose.

Here’s a tip for all English learners (and most everyone else): Do not go to large language models (LLMs) for advice. They simply cannot be trusted. Don’t trust them. Ignore their advice. Pay them no heed.

So you meant "He made my Tshirt muddy" is wrong? Because my Tshirt is not like a field and somewhere else mud flew on to it right?

He made my tee shirt muddy isn’t exactly wrong: people will understand your meaning.  But it’s not quite idiomatic either.

It sounds as though he deliberately smeared mud on your T-shirt! Our clothes and shoes get muddy unintentionally when we are out of doors in wet weather, and the floor gets muddy when we come indoors in muddy shoes. You could complain that someone has made the floor muddy if they carelessly came too far into the house without taking off their dirty shoes.

Some people on Quora said like me, Thai is "make" is stronger than "get" and "make" is more intentional while "get" is more unintentional. https://www.quora.com/Someone-said-make-something-muddy-meaning-that-thing-is-a-place-like-a-field-that-can-be-turned-into-mud-and-get-something-muddy-meaning-that-thing-like-my-clothes-receiving-the-mud-What-is-the-difference-between/answer/Richard-Lueger?filter=all&nsrc=notif_page&sncid=53334922198&snid3=71527296575

OK. How will you decide what answer satisfies you? I don't mean, "What answer will satisfy you?" I mean, "How will you decide?"

If you say all muddy you'll sound native.

You got the floor all muddy!


This answer does not address the main point of the question: the distinction between 'make' and 'get'.

@TimSparkles . I've answered OP's question, which is posed in the final sentence of the post. [Do you say "You got the floor muddy"...]  I've given OP an idiomatic way of expressing what he wants to express, using "got" while providing some lagniappe with all.  OP didn't ask for an essay on the nuanced differences between make and get.   If you feel like enlightening us on those differences, give an answer along those lines.

You can get the floor muddy without getting it all muddy.

@RonJohn Thanks tor enlightening me, dude.

Yes.

You got the floor muddy

is absolutely normal and correct. Native speakers use it all the time. The relevant definition is 5c from Mirriam Webster:

to cause to be in a certain position or condition

You caused the floor to be muddy.
The construct is used in lots of other places and you've specify some of them.
